# How to start, stop, restart a service

Tags: services

Back some versions ago, when I wanted to restart, stop, start a sevice i would do something similar to this:

`sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop` to stop the apache service
`sudo /etc/init.d/networking start` to start the networking service

Etc...

But now it has changed. How can I start, stop, restart any service in the latest Ubuntu with the new way.