# Is there an rcconf equivalent for upstart that works on the command line?

Tags: system, upstart, services

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to start, stop, restart a service](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56896/how-to-start-stop-restart-a-service)

While I'm a big fan of upstart I would like to see a rcconf tool that can manage both traditional sysv services as well as upstart in a quick visual way through the command line, for use over ssh.

Does any unified tool like this exist?